# Inverse Laplace transform $\lim_{s\to \infty } Y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Consider the following initial value problem:

$$y''+2ty-4y=1, \ \ y(0)=0 \textrm{ and } y'(0)=0. $$

Taking Laplace transform:

$$Y(s) = \frac{1}{s^3} + c\frac{e^{s^2/4}}{s^3} $$

and  $\lim_{s\to \infty } Y=0$ shows c=0

---

However, from what I have remembered,

$\lim_{s\to \infty } Y=0$ applies to y such that y is of exponential order and piecewise continuous function.

I know there is a uniqueness theorem for second order equation, so it's safe to say this (let $c=0$) is the only solution.
But the theorem doesn't tell anything about solution itself,
the solution can be anything(not of exponential order etc.).

It seems $\lim_{s\to \infty } Y=0$ cannot be used here.

Then how we can just say $c=0$?

Comment: Surely you understand that the problem comes before: you need to know that $Y$ is well defined before trying to apply a theorem in order to determine something about it. So really (if you want to be rigorous) you need to know something about the behavior of the solution before computing anything using $Y$. In the present case you can use the variation of constants formula.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{s\to\infty} Y(s) = 0$, then the constant $c$ must be zero since

$$ \frac{e^{s^2/4}}{s^3}\longrightarrow\infty \ \ \textrm{ as }s\longrightarrow\infty. $$

Comment: The question is :
 lims→∞Y(s)=0 only applies to some well-behaved functions. In general it is not true (for example, delta function). Why here we can just assert it is true?

Comment: @MathTheNovice You have an explicit form of $Y(s)$ in this case.